# Thin vs thick adapter (wrapper) example 

Tags: c++, design-patterns, definition

I can't find any info on what is the difference between a thin and thick adapter. I would appreciate if someone can provide a description, followed with a simple example (Please note that the example doesn't need to be in C++).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: my vision of this is something like a [class adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Class_Adapter_pattern) that requires minimum changes to conform to an expected interface.

Comment: I never heard of thin and thick adapters. Where did you get those? As far as I know, only adapter pattern exists.

Comment: Well, I actually receive a request to make one for some class. BTW, this is the only info I found so far: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/davidlinthicum/thick-and-thin-adapters-4599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple.

For example, lets say you want to use [the stat function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) in your code, but you want to be able to unit test your code, or even change which function to use at runtime. Then you would add a base class :

```
struct FunctionApiBase
{
 virtual ~FunctionApiBase{}

 virtual int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf) = 0;
};
```

implement it :

```
struct RealFunctionApi : public FunctionApiBase
{
  virtual int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf)
  {
    ::stat( path, buf );
  }
};
```

Then create object of type RealFunctionApi and call stat on it, instead of the real function.

If I understand the text in your link, thick adapter only has more complex code.

Comment: Can you recommend any further reading on Thick and Thin Wrappers? Thanks a lot

Comment: @kburlz Not really. What I suggested is a standard way of doing dependency injection. There is a link under the question